# How to find location of third "_" in a string - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a JavaScript variable which contains something like `"fld_34_46_name"`. I need to be able to find the location of the THIRD `_`. The numbers, and ***name*** are not always the same (so, the string might also look like `"fld_545425_9075_different name_test"`).

Is this possible? How could I do it?

Comment: Is the format always the same?  Would `lastIndexOf('_')` work?

Comment: Hi, There might be an underscore in the name part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `indexOf` method three times:

```
var i = s.indexOf('_');
i = s.indexOf('_', i + 1);
i = s.indexOf('_', i + 1);
```

Note: If the string might contain fewer than three underscores, you would need to check for `-1` after each time.